# Using closure results for Turing-decidable languages

Tags: closures, turing-machines

I have a language L1 = {w in {0,1}*| w contains the same number of 1's and 0's} and i have a TM M that decides L1.

I want to prove that L2 = {w in {0,1}*| w contains more 1's than 0's} is Turing-decidable.

I have used the "closed under complement" approach and proven that M' decides the complement of L1 (~L1).

My question is, can I assume that the ~L1 = (L2 or ~L2) and conclude that since M' decides ~L1 that L2 and ~L2 are both decidable languages?

Thank you for any advice
(Sorry, haven't figured out how to use LaTex here yet...)

Comment: `~L1` is not `L2 or ~L2`. `~L2` contains `L1`: `L2` is `number of 1s > number of 0s`, so `~L2` is `number of 1s <= number of 0s`. The complement of `>` is `<=`, not `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to flesh out Wellbog's answer. Here is L1 (Read n<sub>1</sub>(w) as "number of 1's in w"):

L1 = {w∈
{0,1}<sup>*</sup>: n<sub>1</sub>(w) = n<sub>0</sub>(w)}

And here is L2:

L2 = {w∈
{0,1}<sup>*</sup>: n<sub>1</sub>(w) > n<sub>0</sub>(w)}

From the other side, L1-bar is:

L1-bar = {w∈
{0,1}<sup>*</sup>: n<sub>1</sub>(w) > n<sub>0</sub>(w) OR n<sub>1</sub>(w) < n<sub>0</sub>(w)}

And clearly, L1-bar and L2 are different.